# Robolectric get access to assets

Tags: android, assets, robolectric

Could someone please tell me how can I get access to ASSETS folder during Robolectric test? At the moment my test failed with FileNotFoundException, since Robolectric searching in the wrong folder.

```
zipFile = RuntimeEnvironment.application.getAssets() + "/" + "myFile.zip";
```

I tried with the above solution, but it looks in a different folder, where is no content at all.
I would like to ignore a manual copy solution. I also have a resources folder but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Can you share why do you need access to assets in tests?

Comment: Yes Eugen, I would like to test if my mocks are set up with a specific case the program should look for my ZIP file in assets and extract it. After the extraction it should call other mocks. I can't test the call of the 'after extraction mocks' since I am getting an exception.

Comment: Check that Robolectric tests are run in module dir. And don't modify your production code